# China intercity taxi / taxi-like transport

Tags: china, taxis

I'm wondering how to move in an easy and fast way between main cities in China to more apart or countryside places.

Is it usual/easy/cheap to arrange a trip by some kind of taxi or private transportation service at the moment? And what is the regular fare for example for 1 hour trip for those kind of services?

–I know some countries where is quite easy to catch a driver on the street or the surroundings of public stations.

Thanks!

P.S. Having in mind we don't speak any word of Chinese and will try to communicate with Mobile apps/dictionaries/maps.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can take a taxi to nearby cities, etc. A taxicab driver in Beijing once told me that he had even taken someone to Shanghai. If you get a taxicab in large cities, the likelihood that the taxi driver (rudely) refuses to carry you is small; in smaller cities the chances are much larger.

However, keep in mind that most cities have a rule that, if your trip is too long, or to remote/countryside areas, such that the taxi can't get a return trip, you need to pay for the return trip as well. Usually, this means you pay a 50%-100% surcharge.

If your trip is really one hour, I estimate that your fare will be anywhere from 200-500 RMB. Taking the surcharge into account, you'll need to pay anywhere from 300-1000 RMB. It's probably better to get a rental car with a driver from a local travel agency in this case.

Comment: In this sense, is thre any Chinese phone App to get taxi rides? Such as Cabify or Uber? Thx!

Comment: @GerardB Yes, there's Didi, which acquired Uber China last year, so they're running Uber in China as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. And last, is it usual or possible to negotiate or to bargain  the price for this kind of trips?

Answer (score 0):

I have a better idea for intercity travel, mostly for cities connected. you can use didi travel, a popular app in China, similar to Uber, there is a sub-selection as shunfengche (hitchhiking) but it's not free, you still have to pay, but much cheaper than taxi.you post your depature location and detination, the free driver will catch your inteneary and take your order and pick you up at your location, convenient and money-saving.

Comment: Thanks. Is this system wide deployed along all China? I'm specially interested to move around more rural areas of Guangxi and Yunnan, smaller cities of Guilin/Yangshuo, etc. To do sightseeing and visit some places.